# Bejeweled board generation

Tags: algorithm

I've recently stumbled upon this question:

> How would you generate a board for Bejeweled game to ensure that on the start there are no jewels that would collapse right away and that theres at least one possible move

I've been thinking about doing it in random, letting them fall if they wish before we actually display the board and say that the probability of having no moves to make at all is very low so that we shouldn't worry about it. 
Is there a better approach?

Comment: How about just a checkerboard pattern of two colors?

Comment: @Sneftel's answer is sufficient to satisfy the minimum requirements. Are there additional preferences you would like to add to these requirements?

Comment: that would make the game repetitive and way too easy at the start and we don't want that I guess ;) it is a valid answer to the question as is though :)

Comment: It's not necessarily enough to ensure that a valid move exists. You want to make sure a bunch of moves will follow. If your board has a single valid move and then ends, the player is probably not going to play again.

Comment: @Geobits funny enough, I've played several bejeweled games where completely random gems are dropped down and sometimes that results in no matches immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One greedy approach would be during generating the board, every time you try to add a random jewel, just check if two previous ones horizontally and vertically are not the same to prevent the first situation (keep in mind the border conditions).

To ensure you have N number of matches, after you generate you can get a random point and update jewels either to the sides or top-bottom to make sure there are possible matches while still making sure the first situation won't happen.